# Recording the parameters of a mix

Tags: software, recording, mixing, dj, mixer

Is there any DJ software available that allows you to record the parameters of a mix -- the offset and speed of the audio inputs, the levels of the left and right channels, the position of the crossfader -- rather than just recording the resulting audio?

I'm envisaging software that would allow you to return to a mix and make small tweaks here and there without "re-performing" it.

Sorry if this is a newbie question, but it's quite hard to google for, because of the homography between the verb "record" and the noun "record"!

Comment: The term you are looking for is probably "program".  There are many variables in setup, so probably many possibilities to achieve what you want, depending on your hardware and software environment.  I've seen  controllers that use DMX programs, and studio mixing consoles can record full programs of faders, levels etc.

Comment: ...or 'automation', which is how you'd do this in a DAW package. I had a little search but I couldn't find anything that seems designed to let you perform a mix and then tweak that performance. Tweaking speeds would actually be a little difficult to handle, because any such speed tweak would need all the time offsets of subsequent events to change - I imagine it could be done but maybe it's a gap in the market! If you don't mind 'programming' your mix rather than performing it, Ableton might be worth looking at.

Comment: Thank you both! I'll take a look at Ableton. I'm really looking for the most straightforward software solution for beat-matched DJ-ing. Ideally there would be a mixture of programming and performing -- if the locations and prominences of the beats were automatically detected in a pre-processing step such that the mix could be beat-locked/bar-locked/phrase-locked, that would simplify the "knock-on effect" problem.

Comment: I should say all of them. Automation is a regular feature even on modern hardware mixing consoles.  That being said, Ableton Live has quite perfected the audio stretching algorithm, and, while it does a very good job in real-time, you can also save the customized stretching into external meta files. But if you're looking for simply beatmatched DJing, Ableton Live might be overkill. NI Traktor might be a better investment. That too being said, you can easily connect any two pieces of music software and sync them together using a "loopback" MIDI driver such as loopMIDI (free), or even go WiFi.